# Catalog price rule not working for customer groups with group price set

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

I set a rule:

[image]

It working fine. However, I have group pricing set for the products that the rule covers and the rule is not working for groups where they have a price set. For the groups without a price set, the rule is working fine.

This is my pricing for the products: 
[image]
Rule works on groups **without** the price set.

Is this normal behaviour? Is there a workaround?

**UPDATE**:

The rule seems to be working for some of the groups with prices on but not for others...

**Magento ver. 1.9.2.4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule worked fine right from the start.

Rule didn't work on group prices where the price was already lower than the discounted one...